# R DBI unsupported column type ANYDATA

Tags: sql, r, database, dbi, roracle

I have a column with type ANYDATA in an oracle database. How can I `get` this data as text into R? Thanks

```
library(ROracle)
DBI::dbExecute(con, "create table anydat (id int not null, anydata sys.anydata)")
DBI::dbExecute(con, "insert into anydat values (1, SYS.ANYDATA.convertVarchar2('yolo'))
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from anydat")
Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data=data, prefetch=prefetch, : unsupported column type
```